# Unable to access Sonar MySQL database Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'sonar'@'glassfishdev.ccs.local' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, ant, hudson, jenkins, sonarqube

I am trying to add Sonar to my Continuous Integration build system. I am using ANT as my build script and I am using the sonar-ant-task-1.1.jar for sonar to generate the reports based on my source code in SVN.

**Problem**
When the build runs and hits the sonar ant task I get the exception as follows:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'sonar'@'glassfishdev.ccs.local' (using password: YES)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1075)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3566)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3498)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:919)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:4004)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1284)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2312)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2122)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:774)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:49)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:375)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:289)
at org.sonar.jpa.session.DriverProxy.connect(DriverDatabaseConnector.java:160)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
at org.sonar.jpa.session.DriverDatabaseConnector.getConnection(DriverDatabaseConnector.java:95)
at org.sonar.jpa.session.AbstractDatabaseConnector.testConnection(AbstractDatabaseConnector.java:185)
... 40 more
```

**What I have done**

**1.** Install MySQL database.

**2.** Create the sonar database, sonar user, and grant permissions by using the script provided in the sonar installation

```
**CREATE DATABASE sonar CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;    
CREATE USER 'sonar' IDENTIFIED BY 'sonar';
GRANT ALL ON sonar.* TO 'sonar'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'sonar';
GRANT ALL ON sonar.* TO 'sonar'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'sonar';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;**
```

**3.** Added the [following](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyse+with+Ant+Task+1.0) to my build script

**4.** Added the following external variables in Jenkins Freestyle build project

```
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://10.120.21.12:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
    sonar.jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    sonar.jdbc.username=sonar
    sonar.jdbc.password=sonar
    sonar.host.url=http://10.120.21.12:9000/
```

**5.** I was also available to connect to the database through my sql client tool to verify that the database, user and permissions statements were executed correctly.

However when Jenkins runs the build it does not seem to know how to connect to the MySQL database.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I ran the following command and that fixed the problem:

    GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'sonar'@'%';

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to run the following command:

**GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'sonar'@'%';**

Comment: Hi Viriato, it's not a good practice to grant all on \*.\*, as this will let the user have the privilage to do everything to your database. Just grant all on sonar.* is working. I tried with SonarQube version 4.5.1.

Answer (score 2):

The right solution is this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `sonar`.* TO 'sonar'@'localhost';
```

As explained [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=31061), connections to localhost occur over a UNIX domain socket. You are likely logging in as an anonymous user to localhost (e.g. ''@localhost).

Comment: This answer helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it with sonar 4.5.2 with grants only on sonar.* and its definitely not working.

It looks like sonarqube requires additionnal privileges to work, personnaly i haven't identified which ones yet, and i'm still using a grant all on the database.