# How to enable build stability plugin in Sonar using Ant and Sonar

Tags: plugins, ant, jenkins, sonarqube

I have copied the Build Stability plugin to Sonar, and restarted the server. Now I should configure my Sonar Ant script to include CI build analysis. I don't know how to do this since all examples are using Maven. I also haven't found any help searching Google.

Comment: Hi.. can you please elaborate.. are you using Jenkins+ Sonar or Sonar-run ?

Comment: I am using Jenkins to execute Sonar process, using Ant target.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192765/sonar-plugin-not-working-for-projects-that-use-ant-as-a-build-script

Comment: I've seen it, but my problem is not running Sonar using Ant. My problem is including the build stability plugin through Ant. Documents describing this are always for Maven.

Comment: It seems that this plugin does not work with non-Maven projects. See http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPLUGINS-1603